# Approximating least squares solution with linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, least-squares

Consider the least-squares problem with linear constraints
$$(P_2)\quad\text{Min }||Ax-b||^2_2\\
Mx\leq d\\
x\in\mathbb{R}^n$$ where WLOG $b\geq 0$.

Probably it's a good approximation of $(P_2)$ to solve the "least-$1$-norm" version, $(P_1)$, where you try to minimize $||Ax-b||_1$ subject to the same linear restrictions. I was thinking that a good approximation to $(P_1)$ could start by solving
$$\text{Min }||Ax-b||_1\\\text{s.t. } Ax\geq b\\Mx\leq d\\x\in\mathbb{R}^n\\
\equiv(P'_1)\quad\text{Min }(1,\ldots,1)Ax\\\text{s.t. } Ax\geq b\\Mx\leq d\\x\in\mathbb{R}^n$$
and then scale down the solution $\bar x$ (assuming $(P_1')$ is feasible) by some factor less than 1 so as to minimize the quantity $||A\bar x-b||_1$.

The reason I think it's "good" (not bad) is because the errors in the three problems follow an affine relation which comes from the equivalence of norms $1$ and $2$. Moreover $(P_1)'$ is naturally way cheaper to solve than $(P_2)$.

Is there some place where this method is mentioned (my searching efforts were unfruitful)?

Comment: What is $M$? A linear functional?

Comment: It is a matrix.

Comment: What size matrix? I understand this if $M$ is a row. If $M$ has more than one row, then $Mx$ is a vector, Then what $Mx\leq d$ means? (I suppose that $d$ is a number).

Comment: The $\leq$ acts component wise. $(1,100)\leq (3,104)$.

Comment: So $d$ is also a vector?

Comment: Yes, it's the common notation in linear programming.

Comment: Do you mean approximation in the sense of the value of the objective function or in terms of the optimal values of the parameters? Either way, I don’t see any reason to expect that this should be a good approximation. Look at the simple case of $A = id$ and $b=0$. The $L^1$ norm will try to make the coordinate variables zero, while the $L^2$ norm will generally find an interior solution.

Comment: Wdym by "interior"? Minimizing $(1,\ldots,1)I_nx$ subject to $I_nx\geq 0$ will generally give a solution $\bar x$ such that $\bar x =I_n\bar x \approx 0$.

Comment: I mean that trying to minimize $||Ax-b|||_2$ is a constant away from minimizing $||Ax-b||_1$.

Comment: Not if 0 is excluded by the constraint.